# What does the StartingPosition flag of a kinesis event source mapping do?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda function that consumes events from a kinesis stream.

I am not sure what the `StartingPosition` flag does in the event source mapping configuration.

Does it only apply during the first invocation of the function? '

After the first innovation, the lambda should keep a checkpoint of the last fetched record so that it knows to start there?